# Strange behavior of C abort function on mingw-w64

Tags: c, windows-10, mingw-w64

I'm new to mingw-w64 and I'm running into the following problem:

I recently installed MSYS on my Windows 10 computer according to the
instructions provided in

[How to install MinGW-w64 and MSYS2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2)

and I am currently trying to build some Win32 C programs. I first tried some
simple programs and they seem to work; however, I ran into problems with
the C abort function.

If I build the following program on Linux

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("bla bla bla\n");
  abort();
}
```

and later run it, I simply get the output

```
bla bla bla
Aborted
```

However, on Windows the output is

```
bla bla bla

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual
way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

A message window also appears with the message

> a.exe has stopped working --
>   A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close
>   the program and notify you if a solution is available.

Is this the way it is supposed to be? Anyway, I much prefer the Linux version.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k089yyh0.aspx

Comment: Yes, that's the way it's supposed to be. Why shouldn't it be that way?

Answer (score 3):

`abort` is the same as `raise(SIGABRT)`.

If you don't catch the `SIGABRT` signal, the default OS handler is invoked, on Linux this is dumping core, causing the shell to write `Aborted` on standard error.

On Windows, it terminates and the message you saw is displayed, on standard error if console subsystem is used or in a standard message box if gui. This can be suppressed by the non-standard `_set_abort_behavior`.

If you want a uniform action across systems, you need to register a `SIGABRT` handler and do something yourself:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void handle_abort(int sig)
{
   // do something (e.g write to log)
   // don't let this handler return if you want to suppress defaut handler
}

int main(void)
{    
    signal(SIGABRT, handle_abort);

    abort();
}
```

Comment: Note that the reason this suppresses the 'default message' is that the program no longer exits as a result of a signal — because you use `exit()` or `_exit()` or something similar.  You can demonstrate the difference with a signal handler like this: `void handle_abort(int sig)
{
   fprintf(stderr, "Abort signal (%d) caught by %s()\n", sig, __func__);
   signal(sig, SIG_DFL);
   raise(sig);
   /*exit(128+sig);*/
}` (or you can use `exit()` instead of `signal()` plus `raise()`).  The 'default message' actually comes from the shell.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're right, corrected that part.